Encoding word association hierarchies in Text Transformers?
I am currently learning about text transformers and have thought of a question about language hierarchy. From my current understanding, a transformer is built through using training data of a large language set where words have associated tags/identifiers that can be then mapped into a multidimensional environment. Words that are encoded map a particular way in the environment and as such other words that map in a similar way will result in a high cosine similarity score.
Thus similar words
happy - smile, good, great
crow - bird, raven, black bird

I ask about encoding hierarchy as there are associations in English that are both true on a macro scale but not on a micro scale. examples being
happy - angry, jealous, sleepy

these are all emotions and in a macro-scale would be great to show up on when performing a similarity calculation. But when looking for similar words on a micro scale (as in words that a synonyms), this association would be considered bad.
And if I am understanding correctly how a model is built, then trying to account for both of these scales would result in a poor encoding.
So ultimately, how does one account for hierarchy when building a sentence transformer? Is it easier to create different transformers based on the different levels or is there a way to encode these hierarchies into the training data?

One doesn't account for this when building a transformer and transformers for language are not trained like that. They are generally trained by representing words (or parts of words, or letters) as unique items (and each gets mapped to a vector representation internally - initially these vectors are random and during training the values eventually move to something useful), then additional processing layers on top that do something with these vectors, and all of that is then trained to perform some objective (e.g. predict the next word going forwards and/or going backwards, or predict the missing word in the middle - all based on LOTS of text examples).
It may turn out that internally the trained model then has representations that somehow reflect these things. You can try this out without too much trouble by using a small language model on e.g. Google Colab (or something similar) - unless you happen to have a very impressive server with nice GPUs at home (in which case you could do it on your machine or maybe even use one of the publicly available large language models).
These internal representation vectors may or may not surprise you in the sense that e.g. on some dimensions emotions might be similarly placed, on another positive things, on another birds etc. - haven't checked, but I'd expect it is at least to some extent representing these things. E.g. there's that famous old example of subtracting the vector representation of "female" from "king" and the closest vector value being "queen". That was with word embeddings, but I'd expect the learned embeddings of a transformer to be similar - if you Google for it, you might even find that someone has already explored this extensively.

Does this mean that words with similar spelling will naturally be closer to each other in the dimensional space? when I performed cosine similarity on the words GIF and GIS, the result came back quite high despite GIF being a graphics format and GIS being geographical instruments.

Not necessarily. If the embeddings are for whole words, I'd guess missspellings of the same word (e.g. "the" and "teh") might end up with similar embeddings and genuinely different words with similar spellings ("demoted" vs. "denoted") would end up with more different representations. For your example, "Winter Haven's Gilbert Airport" (GIF) and "Gisborne Airport" (GIS) are very similar concepts. ;) Who knows what GIF and GIS most get used as/in which context. For GIF the graphcis format seems likely (and I'd have thought "jpg",  "jpeg", "png" etc. would end up close to it), GIS not so common?

thanks for the explanation. It sounds like I will have to build my own transformer to control for the embeddings and to tailor the transformer for the specific tasks I am trying to build
